# Ffmpeg libx264rgb and libx264 yuv444p gives very different results

Tags: video, ffmpeg, compression, libx264

I am trying to create a lossy compressed video from several .png files. I am using the following ffmpeg commdans:

```
ffmpeg -i %8d.png -frames:v 4 -c:v libx264rgb -pix_fmt rgb24 -g 4 -qp 30 -r 25 out.mp4
```

and

```
ffmpeg -i %8d.png -frames:v 4 -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv444p -g 4 -qp 30 -r 25 out.mp4
```

Then I am extracting frames from the videos with the command:

```
ffmpeg -i out.mp4 -r 25 %8d.png
```

When I compare the bitrate and PSNR, I found that the yuv444p gives about 2 db gain at the same bitrate. Why such a huge difference is observed even I did set yuv444p which does not apply chroma subsampling?

Comment: Could it be because of the lossy color conversion? see for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22496938/lossless-rgb24-to-yuv444-transformation